# Python - Change the socket address of existing .exe application

Tags: python, windows, sockets, client, ip

How do I with python change the port and address information of a client .exe application?
So instead of programming your own client where you assign it initially, you change the ip information of an already existing client using python. An ip-changer, I suppose :)

(Windows, python 2.6)

Comment: Your question is incredibly unclear. Who's the client? Who's the server? What's the protocol? What exactly is your goal?

Comment: ops wait accidentaly pressed enter

Comment: I am trying to make a tibia ip-changer. So I want to configure the tibia client to connect to my own server. So maybe port: 7171, and address: 127.0.0.1, protocol: TCP

Comment: You're trying to make a [Tibia client](http://www.tibiaclient.com/) connect to your own server? Does the client not offer the ability to change the IP address and port that it tries to connect to? If not, and if it's not open source, you'll need to hack the binary executable or poison your computer's DNS to point `server.tibiagame.example` to `127.0.0.1` or something similar. This might not be something that can be done simply by writing a Python program.

Comment: Ok thanks guys, I need to look what I've got. etc/hosts is interesting...

Comment: My goal would be only the fun of learning and succeding since there are plenty of ip-changers out there for download, and I could just modify the appliction using an hex editor. Anyways the GUI is ready, the only thing lacking is the function which appearantly is hard to create. It would be fun to share the result with my friends also...

Answer (score 0):

If your application has a host name buried in it that it tries to contact, your simplest approach is to leave the port alone and modify your /etc/hosts file (C:/Windows/ System32/drivers/etc/hosts on Windows) so that the host name resolves to 127.0.0.1.

For instance:

```
127.0.0.1       tibia.com
```